# Java JobRunr when using Spring Boot Redis Starter

Tags: spring-boot, jobrunr

How do I create and use the Redis connection that `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` creates?  It doesn't seem like there is a Bean for `RedisClient` created by the default auto configuration so I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

The documentation does state that in this case you need to create the `StorageProvider` yourself which is fine, but can you reuse what Spring Boot has already created.  I believe this would need to be a pooled connection which you would also need to enable through Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

RedisTemplate offers a high-level abstraction for Redis interactions:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template

Redis autoconfiguration :

```
    @AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnClass({RedisOperations.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({RedisProperties.class})
@Import({LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class, JedisConnectionConfiguration.class})
public class RedisAutoConfiguration {
    public RedisAutoConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(
        name = {"redisTemplate"}
    )
    @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(RedisConnectionFactory.class)
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(RedisConnectionFactory.class)
    public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.redis.jedis.pool.enabled) you can find the corresponding configuration properties(including connection pool default configuration).

Simple implementation example :
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-redis-tutorial

Comment: Exactly, and we're using those in our application. The problem is JobRunr expects a `RedisClient` with Lettuce, and that is not autoconfigured an any way, and needs to be provided manually as far as I can tell. It's not the biggest of deals, it's just annoying and slightly repetitive.